# Array behaviour difference in PowerShell 2 to PowerShell 3

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have observed a difference in behavior between PowerShell 2.0 code and 3.0 code but can't seem to fix it. I am hoping I can get some help.  Please see code below.
If you run this in V2 (please change ServerA and ServerB to a server on your network) you will see after selecting and clicking the button, write-host shows them as seperate names. In version 3 the listbox populates it as 1.

```
$Servers = @()
[array]$ServerstoPing = ("ServerA","ServerB")



    # Generate the form
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
    $Form1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form1.Text = "Ping Some Servers"
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::regular)
    $Fontboxes = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::regular)
    $Fontdate = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
    $FontProgress = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
    $Form1.Font = $Font


    $Serverlistbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
    $Serverlistbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(11,137) 
    $Serverlistbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,170) 
    $Serverlistbox.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"
    $Serverlistbox.font = $Fontboxes
    foreach($item in $ServerstoPing){
        [void] $Serverlistbox.Items.Add("$item")
        }
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Serverlistbox)

    $SubmitButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.button
    $SubmitButton.text = "Ping Servers"
    $SubmitButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(171,305)
    $SubmitButton.AutoSize = $True
    $Form1.Controls.Add($SubmitButton)
    $Form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

    $OutputPing = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $OutputPing.MultiLine = $True
    $OutputPing.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $OutputPing.text = "Server ping status will be displayed here once done'."
    $OutputPing.font = $Fontboxes
    $OutputPing.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(226,40)
    $OutputPing.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,255)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($OutputPing)




$SubmitButton.add_click({    
#foreach ($objItem in $ServerstoPing)
    foreach ($objItem in $Serverlistbox.SelectedItems)
        {
        $Servers += $objItem
        }

write-host $ServerstoPing

    Foreach($server in $servers)
        {
       ping -n 1 -w 1000 $server | out-null
       if($? -eq $true){
            write-host ("$server ping success")
       } 
       else 
          {
          write-host ("$server did not respond to ping, not extracting events")
       }
        }

       })
$Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yep. Sorry thats declared earlier. Its quite a long piece of code. I  have that variable declared already

Comment: I have added full code as an example which can be copied and pasted. Thanks

Comment: @ADTJOB `$servers = @()` should be inside event handler. And I would rather use `$servers = @($Serverlistbox.SelectedItems)`, then loop with array addition.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Thank you. Do you know what changed between 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: @ADTJOB Many things changed, although I can point to two particular things, things which make your code work different: 1) `ScriptBlock` invoked as delegate create new scope in v3+ `&{ $a=1; ([Func[object]]{ $a=2; $a }).Invoke(); $a }`. 2) Compound assignment work differently (IMHO bug) in v3+ `&{ $a=1; &{ $a+=2; $a }; $a }`.